# How to send GET Request in curl with X-Forwarded-For?

Tags: php, curl

EDIT:

```
<?php
$url = "http://website/ip";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X_FORWARDED_FOR: 127.0.0.1"));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

I get the ip address of the host,

but how i send the get request with my computer ip?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `X_FORWARDED_FOR` is not sent via `GET` parameter.
You can set it using `curl_setopt`, for example:

```
$url = "http://mywebsite/ip";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X_FORWARDED_FOR: 127.0.0.1"));
```

Comment: I updated the post, tell me what I did wrong please in the result I still get the ip address of the host

Comment: @ben Instead of  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] put your IP address

Comment: The IP of the host still appears